# Question regarding Churels

Tags: puranas, kali, evil, churel

Churels are often associated with spirits on The peepal tree

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Churel

My questions

1. Who are churels, are they Dayans
2. Are there any mention about these evil entities in the puranas

The article mentions

> This demon also has associations with the various accounts of the Mother Goddess as well as the Rakshasi.[1] Within Hindu belief, Churels may turn into dakinis and serve the goddess Kali, joining the goddess in her routine of feasting on human flesh and blood.[13]

I still don't get how can evil entity as a Churel worship Kali? Kali being the supreme Goddess supports Dharma which is against evil doings, How can a Churel worship her?
However Dakinis are bad only to the wrong doers But What about Churels?